# Change the look & feel of button

Tags: html, css

we have a button, its displaying like this :

[image]

we want to display like :

[image]

```css
.saveall
{
 
text-transform: capitalize;

font-weight: bold;
float: left;
        text-align: center;
        color: #fff;

background: #3fbdf7;
font: 500 14px/1.35 Roboto Slab,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
overflow: visible;
        width: auto;
        cursor: pointer;
vertical-align: middle;

display: inline-table;
        padding: 9px;
        position: relative;

        margin-left: 6px;
        margin-right: 6px;

}
```

```html
<button class="saveall" title="Save all'" type="button" style="float: left;padding: 5px 5px 5px 0;" onclick="changeaction()"  id="mass_update_butn">
       <span><span>Invoice</span></span>
</button>
```

Please help me to find solution

thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems simple enough.

Remove the inline styling and the border, then tweak the padding.

Those inner spand aren't really necessary unless you have a particular reason for having them.

```css
.saveall {
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  background: #3fbdf7;
  font: 500 14px/1.35 Roboto Slab, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  cursor: pointer;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 24px;
  position: relative;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="saveall" title="Save all'" type="button" onclick="changeaction()" id="mass_update_butn">
  Invoice
</button>
```

Comment: did you answered before i posted question :-) you are express..... i can  accept answer in 8 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```css
button {
  border: none;
  background: #3FBDF7;
  color: white;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 25px;
}
```

```html
<button>Invoice</button>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked for me. but as Paulie_D gave answer first, i will accept that answer